# Truncate <style> tag data from a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, script-tag

I have a string let's say **headData** which is combination of `<script>` and `<style>` tags. For Ex(with Dummy data) -

```
let headData = '<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(path-to.woff) format('woff');
        }</style>
    <script>var isPresent = false;</script>
    <script>var isContent = true;</script>
    <style>@font-face {
            font-family: 'Courgette';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Courgette Regular'), local('Courgette-Regular'), url(path-to.woff2) format('woff2');}</style>'
```

I inject whole of headData in  tag like below.

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: headData}} />
```

I don't want to inject `<style>` tag related data and only want all the `<script>` tag related data to be injected.

So what I finally want to inject is similar to -

```
let headData = '<script>var isPresent = false;</script>
        <script>var isContent = true;</script>'
```

What is the right way to achieve this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegEx with *Capturing Groups* to replace the *style* tag and it's content for all occurrences:

```
/(<style>)[^<>]*(<\/style>)/g
```

**Where:**

**`(<style>)` - 1st Capturing Group**

`<style>` matches the characters `<style>` literally (case sensitive)

`[^<>]*` match a single character not present in the following

1. `*` Quantifier  matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
2. `<>` matches a single character in the list `<>`

**`(<\/style>)` - 2nd Capturing Group**

`g` global modifier. Matches all(doesn't return after first match)

**Demo:**

```js
let headData = `<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(path-to.woff) format('woff');
        }</style>
    <script>var isPresent = false;<\/script>
    <script>var isContent = true;<\/script>
    <style>@font-face {
            font-family: 'Courgette';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Courgette Regular'), local('Courgette-Regular'), url(path-to.woff2) format('woff2');}</style>`;
            
 var re = /(<style>)[^<>]*(<\/style>)/g;
 headData = headData.replace(re,'').trim();
 console.log(headData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked fine. If I want to select only <script> tag how can I achieve that? I created a new post for this question if you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150137/include-only-script-tag-from-page-source

Comment: @ShantanuTomar, I have posted my answer pretty much the same way here (just adding `|` conditional), please check:)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there a way we can only check for including <script> tag rather then excluding other tags.  As my need is to only include script tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `DOMParser` to transform it into a document, remove everything that's a `<style>`, then take the inner HTML:

```js
const headData = `<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(path-to.woff) format('woff');
        }</style>
    <script>var isPresent = false;<\/script>
    <script>var isContent = true;<\/script>
    <style>@font-face {
            font-family: 'Courgette';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Courgette Regular'), local('Courgette-Regular'), url(path-to.woff2) format('woff2');}</style>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(headData, 'text/html');
for (const style of doc.querySelectorAll('style')) {
  style.remove();
}
const trimmedText = doc.head.innerHTML;
console.log(trimmedText);
```