# Include only <script> tag from page source

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, styles, script-tag

I have a string let's say headData which is a combination of `<script>`, `<style>` and `<link>` tags. For Ex(with Dummy data) -

```
let headData = '<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(path-to.woff) format('woff');
        }</style>
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//assets.adobedtm.com">
    <script>var isPresent = false;</script>
    <script>var isContent = true;</script>
    <style>@font-face {
            font-family: 'Courgette';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Courgette Regular'), local('Courgette-Regular'), url(path-to.woff2) format('woff2');}</style>'
```

I inject whole of headData in a tag like below.

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: headData}} />
```

I don't want to inject HTML tags like `<style>, <link>` tag related data and only want all the `<script>` tag related data to be injected. Is there a way I can achieve this using regex of selecting only `<script>` tags.

So what I finally want to inject is similar to -

```
let headData = '<script>var isPresent = false;</script>
        <script>var isContent = true;</script>'
```

What is the right way to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: Do you wan to just place the javascript in `script` tag or **execute** it as well ?

Comment: It will be executed, this is just dummy which I provided in the question, for real, I will be having GTM and Adobe scripts to be executed. I just want to filter out HTML tags and only include <script> tags

Comment: I think filtration is possible but I am not sure if it will be executed as inline script... since all inline scripts are executed only once at the load time

Comment: How to possibly achieve the filtration. As I am sure it will be executed. You can see a similar question posted by me which is working fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59947262/truncate-style-tag-data-from-a-string

Comment: I have posted code that filters the `scripts` check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the wanted tags with RegEx ***Capturing Groups*** and `match()`:

```
/(<script>)[^<>]*(<\/script>)/g
```

**Demo:**

```js
let headData = `<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 300;
            src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(path-to.woff) format('woff');
        }</style>
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//assets.adobedtm.com" />
    <script>var isPresent = false;<\/script>
    <script>var isContent = true;<\/script>
    <style>@font-face {
            font-family: 'Courgette';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Courgette Regular'), local('Courgette-Regular'), url(path-to.woff2) format('woff2');}</style>`;
            
 var re = /(<script>)[^<>]*(<\/script>)/g;
 headData = headData.match(re).join('\n');
 console.log(headData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there a way we can only check for including <script> tag rather then excluding other tags. As my need is to only include script tag

Comment: @ShantanuTomar, I have updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: It does, but only extracts first <script> tag data including opening and closing script tags and then stops.

Comment: @ShantanuTomar, I don't know why you getting single occurrence, I have tested in FireFox and Chrome and got both the occurrences as expected:)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with React, but **it is generally not a good idea to try to parse HTML using regular expressions**.

You could run into all kinds of problems with regular expressions. (For example, some of the script tags could contain code like this: `<script> const myString='<script></script>'; </script>`).

I would suggest using the browser's built-in parser rather than regular expressions to extract the script tags and their content.

```
function getScriptsString(headString) {
  const head = document.createElement('head');
  head.innerHTML = headData;
  const headChildrenArray = Array.from(head.children);
  const scriptsString = headChildrenArray.reduce((str,el) => {
    if(el.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
      return str + el.outerHTML;
    }
    return str;
  }, '');
  return scriptsString;
}
```